# It is possible to set property value via reflection in nsubstitute proxy object?

Tags: c#, reflection, nsubstitute

Im trying to mock interface and set properties via reflection. But I get null reference exception. Is any way to do this ? I also create instance of this proxy by FormatterServices.GetSafeUninitializedObject().
[image]

Comment: [Yes you can use reflection](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/222#issuecomment-193487145). Without more info I'm guessing the problem here is `GetSafeUninitializedObject`.

Comment: you were right. Nsubstitute creates instance of proxy object  itself when I invoke
`Substitute.For<T>();`.